# Приложение карт вылетает при добавлении Listener'a к Spinner

Tags: java, android

делаю приложение по шаблону google maps activity. На данный момент в приложение добавлена карта от шаблона (`fragment`) и `Spinner`. При добавлении `Listener`'a для `Spinner`'a приложение вылетает при запуске. Вот код `OnCreate`:

```
radius = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.alarm_radius);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterNumber = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.number, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
adapterNumber.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
radius.setAdapter(adapterNumber);
radius.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int r = radius.getSelectedItemPosition();
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(point)
            .radius(r));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
//Всё остальное - настройка карты
```

Насколько я понял, параметр `this` в `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.number, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` - это `fragment`, поэтому `Listener` и не создаётся. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы `Listener` для `Spinner`'a добавился и заработал?

Comment: возможно у вас не определен `mMap`. Добавьте стектрэйс ошибки в вопрос. Если дело в `this`, используйте `getActivity()` или передавайте в адаптер контекст

Comment: @Jarvis_J без листенера все работает, `mMap` определен

Comment: стектрейс ошибки то покажете? у меня ваш код работает (`mMap.addCircle(...)` закомменчивал)

Comment: @Jarvis_J извиняюсь за введение в заблуждение. Не работало, потому что mMap не успевал подгрузиться и вылетал NullPointerException

Comment: хорошо, что разобрались)